# How to hide all the comments in Zend Studio?

Tags: php, zend-studio

I wonder whether there is a hotkey that can hide all the comments both '//' and '/* */' ?
So the real effective code is clear.
and where can I find a Zend tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Zend studio, there is no way to hide the mark '/**/'.In other IDE, you can hide